# "Git show" on the previouse SHA on a specific file

Tags: git

I need to run "git show" on the previous commit but for a specific file. I used the following command, however it is not working.

git show SHA~1:file_path

What could be the possible working command?

Comment: `git show <hash>:<path>` will show the contents of that particular path. What did you want instead?

Comment: @torek I think the OP wants to see the patch for a particular file. But that's what `git diff` is for.

Comment: I want to get a content of specific file for one version before a specific reversion. 
git show <hash>:<path> is working but unfortunately 
git show <hash~1>:<path> is not working.

Comment: _"it is not working"_ - how is it not working? Is there an error or some unexpected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem as this command should work.

This commands shows the complete file as it was on the specific commit you're telling it to.

If you want to show the diff on that commit for that patch to your local workdir, use that syntax instead:

```
git diff <revision> <path>

git diff SHA~1 file_path
```

If you want to show the patch for that file, use

```
git log -p -1 <revision> <path>
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response, But I want to just use "git show" not other command. 
Is there anyway I can get previous command sha rather than using the sha~1?

Comment: To get the parent commit of your head, you can use `git log --pretty='format:%H' HEAD^ -1`

Comment: thank you for your comment.
I want to get the previous sha for an arbitrary sha not just for HEAD sha.

Comment: They just use `git log --pretty='format:%H' MYSHA^ -1 `

Answer (score 0):

Running `git show` on a commit will only show the diff associated to that commit. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show):

> For commits it shows the log message and textual diff.

If you want to see the diff for a particular file, you need to use `git diff` with the [range syntax](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges):

```
git diff SHA-1^:path/to/file..SHA-1:path/to/file
```

This will show you the differences in `path/to/file` between the commit with the specified SHA-1 and its parent, referenced with `SHA-1^`. You can read about the different ways of referencing parents commits in the documentation about [ancestry references](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Ancestry-References).

Comment: 'git show <SHA>:<File Path>' show the content of repository for a specific file and a specific version.
My question is how can get same result for the previous version sha just sing git show command.

Comment: I see. What shell are you using?

Comment: Actually I am not using shell command. 
I am using gitpython to run git commands.
`res = repository.git.show("%s:%s" % (revision, 'file_path'))`
but it dose not working for 
`res = repository.git.show("%s:%s" % (revision+'~1', 'file_path'))`
And I find out git also not working with similar command.

Comment: That's a rather important detail. You might want to include that in your question ;) Running `git show SHA-1^:path/to/file` works in the shell, so it must be something specific to the library you're using.

Comment: I am using ubuntu shell.
It is not working in my working environment. I received following message:
`fatal: Invalid object name 'ace83d9d2a97cfe8a8aa9bdd7b46ce71713fb494-1^'.`

Comment: Where does that `-1` right before the `^` character come from? That's not part of a commit hash.